# Outputting table format for Python pandas data frame from inside method inside object

Tags: python, oop, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have Python 2.7 on an Anaconda distribution of Jupyter/IPython notebooks.  If a `pandas` dataframe is the last thing in a coding cell, it outputs with a nice clean table formatting (cells are surrounded by nice black border).

If it is not the last printed or outputted line in the cell, you have to wrap it in `print()` to get it to output, and you lose the nice table formatting that is the default if you make it the last line of the cell.  I believe this problem behaves the same in 3.x as well.  Is there a way to tell Python to output the df table formatting when the df is not the last line of code in the cell?  As per the rest of this post, is there a way to make this work from within a method within object code (which is what I am really trying to do) ?

**To help investigate this:**

This Outputs nice table around the DF:

```
# rest of my code here
myDF
```

This Does not output the table formatting, it just spits out the content:

```
# my code
print(myDF)
print("other stuff ...")
# more code might be here ...
```

When I tried to use the syntax of making the DF the last line of a function call inside an object, it did not output at all (sample code follows).  To fix it, I would think that wrapping it in `print()` is the only option, but I would really like to keep the nice table formatting.  Is there a way to do this?

The code where this does not work right now:

Outputs nothing:

```
class MyObject(MyBaseObject):
    # few global variables here used by the class itself
    def __init__(self, some args ...):
        # Some code that happens in the initialization method
        # includes super() for MyBaseObject class       
        if moveList == "Stored":
            _localDF = self.get_solutionDF()
            _localDF

    def get_solutionDF(self):
        #  returns a DF created during initialization method
```

To Output the DF but does not wrap it in nice table formatting:

simply modify above code by wrapping `localDF` in `print()` statements.  I captured the output of `get_solutionDF()` in a variable as an experiment after simply ending the function with `self.get_solutionDF()` did not output anything but this did not help (still no output).

Ideas welcome.  The solution may help with other code as well once a way is found to keep the pretty table when a DF is output by other means then simply making it the last line of a Jupyter code cell.  Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to display a nice table from within a function use display instead of print. I used it to print pandas style format this is the code that worked for me:

```
from Ipython.display import display
while True:
    #some operation that generates a pandas dataframe "df"
    display(df)
    break
```

Note:  If the above import command throws an error under your implementation, try using this import command instead:

```
import ipython_genutils
```

This variant was needed for a user with Anaconda and Python 3.6

`